# Can I use SizeChange event in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to change Button drawing based on button size using XAML.
I know it is possible using c# code not sure about XAML
Thanks

Update :
my code is like

```
<Grid Width="60" Height="60">
       <Ellipse Width="57" Height="57" StrockThickness="1">
       </Ellipse>
</Grid>
```

I am applying above style to Button control. but here Width/Height is hard coded. I want it dynamically design time. so when I increase/decrease button size ellipse become accordingly

Thanks again

Comment: How much are you trying to do in XAML? You should be able to add the event handler, but you *probably* want to implement the handler in straight C#.

Comment: When do you want to change the appearance exactly? Do you have some limits, e.g. if width is smaller than 100, then use layout 1, if it is between 100 and 500, then use layout 2, and so on? Or what is your scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [Property or Event triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294856.aspx) (in XAML). This is probably the preferred way to do this kind of behaviour as it puts the User Experience completely in the designers hands (via XAML) rather than hooking up event handlers (in C# code) that a developer now needs to maintain in order to modify the user experience.

I don't have quick access to VS to test this out right now, but I can try tomorrow if there is no answer by then.